Agregar scrollbar Funcional tkinter python
Mi problema es que estoy intentando agregar un scrollbar a un listbox, si pongo como "contenedor padre" del listbox no me deja utilizarlo, ya que me proporciona el error:

_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!frame.!frame2.!listbox3 which already has slaves managed by pack

Entiendo que es porque estoy utilizando grid en algo con pack.
Se que no son las formas correctas de hacerlo ya que debería hacerlo utilizando un canvas quizá, pero estoy intentando realizarlo de esta manera y la idea es resolverlo utilizando eso.
def Actualizar_Pendientes():
    for widget in frame2.winfo_children(): 
        widget.destroy()

    listbox = tk.Listbox(frame2, width=20, height=7, bg=GRIS)
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(listbox, orient="vertical", command=listbox.yview)
    listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=False, padx=5, pady=5)
    scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    listbox.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=230)
    for i, turno in enumerate(leer_turnos(),start=1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            color_lista = "#808080" 
        else:
            color_lista = "#666666"
        label_turno = tk.Label(listbox, text=f"Paciente: {turno[1]}, Tratamiento: {turno[2]}, Entrega: {turno[3]}, Costo:$ {turno[4]}, Registrado en: {turno[5]}", font="ARIAL 13", bg=color_lista,fg="WHITE")
        label_turno.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')
        btn_Editar = tk.Button(listbox,text="Editar", bg=GRIS_ULTRA_OSCURO,fg="WHITE",height=1,width=10,font="ARIAL 8")
        btn_Editar.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='w')
        btn_Eliminar = tk.Button(listbox,text="Eliminar", bg=GRIS_ULTRA_OSCURO,fg="WHITE",height=1,width=10,font="ARIAL 8")
        btn_Eliminar.grid(row=i, column=2, sticky='w')
        btn_T_Volver = tk.Button(frame2,text="MENU",font="ARIAL 12", bg=GRIS_ULTRA_OSCURO, fg="WHITE", height=3, width=50, command=lambda:Mostrar_Frames(frame1))
        btn_T_Volver.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.60)


En esta imagen muestra como se ve, la idea es que aparezca el scroolbar ahí para poder seguir bajando entre los registros y que los botones esten ligados al registro en cuestion

Estás usando mal el listbox, un listbox sirve para mostrar una lista de cadenas (texto) exclusivamente. Estás intentando forzarlo  usando grid para posicionar widgets dentro del listbox, pero esos datos no forman parte de los datos del listbox y no usan su funcionalidad, entre otras cosas no pueden ser seleccionados o habilitar el scroll. En tu caso un frame scrollable con un canvas es lo más conveniente.

@FJSevilla Y si pasara los datos como texto? porque lo pensé y podría funcionar, pero el problema seria asignarle los botones a los datos en cuestión ¿ se te ocurre alguna manera de poder asignarle un boton a esos elementos? para ser honesto se que la mejor opcion es un canvas y frame, pero no tengo la menor idea de como va canva , la idea es no aprender eso ahora por eso busca una alternativa con lo que "se"tambien se que un chatgpt podria hacerlo por mi pero no es el objetivo, gracias por tomarte el tiempo en ayudarme

*busco (no quiero quedar como que impongo que busques)

El problema es que cada linea de texto, cada item del listbox,  lleva asociada dos botones. Esos botones no pueden ir dentro del listbox pero deberían sincronizarse con los items de éste (sincronizar el scroll, el redimensionado, etc) y eso es complicado.... Podrías usar un listbox con las opciones como  texto y luego dos botones externos  (no uno por cada item, solo dos) y asociar sus acciones (editar y eliminar) al item seleccionado en el listbox en ese momento. O si quieres mantener los dos botones por línea, insisto en que el frame con el canvas es de lejos lo más simple.
